# C# Error in updating textBox and converting data in it after calculation

Tags: c#

Im kinda new to C# and hawing a problem with a code.

```
            private void tbSold_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbSold.Text = tbSold.Text.Replace(',', '.');
        tbSold.Select(tbSold.Text.Length, 0);


        double BO = Convert.ToDouble(tbBought.Text);
        double SO = Convert.ToDouble(tbSold.Text);
        double TOT = ((SO / BO) * 100);
        tbTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(TOT +"%");
    }
```

Now the explanation and the question. The first part of the code is for replacing the coma with the dot so I can insert the data in SQLExpress.

But I also want to hawe the percantage displayed in tbTotal. Im hawing 2 problems here. One is that I get a error if I delete all the characters in the tbSold textBox. No matter If they were decimal or not ... and the second is that I dont get the corect value if there is a decimal value.

If I put the conversion in the buttonClick event for inserting in the database, I get my data inserted but getting the error afterwards.

I now Im probably missing something simple but cant figure it out

Comment: What error do you get?  On what line?

Comment: I can run the aplication ... but if I enter some value in tbSold and delete the value after that I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot convert a blank string (`""`) to a double - you will get a `FormatException`.  I would add some checking for blank strings (and for `0` in the `Bought` field:

```
private void tbSold_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tbSold.Text = tbSold.Text.Replace(',', '.');
    tbSold.Select(tbSold.Text.Length, 0);


    double BO; 
    bool boughtPrased = double.TryParse(tbBought.Text, out BO);
    // what should you do if the parse fails?

    double SO;
    bool soldParsed = double.Parse(tbSold.Text, out SO);
    // what should you do if the parse fails?

    double TOT = (SO / BO);  // convert to percentage in format below
    // what do you do if BO is 0?

    // display as percentage with two decimal digits
    tbTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:P2}",TOT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks thanks alot for the help ... Im not getting any errors anymore ... but I will now disable the buttons for inserting the data in the database so I dont get unexpected errors and a error msg in the status bar. If Im not wrong I should be good with 'if (double.TryParse(tbBought.Text, out BO) == false)
            {
                
            }'